# disable sunday on react-native-calendar-picker react native

Tags: react-native, calendar

I want to disable sunday in react-native-calendar-picker. Here what i have done, but not worked yet

```
const disableDate = () => {
    let date = new Date()
    return date.getDay() == 0 ? true : false
}
```

and in the calendar

```
<CalendarPicker
   minDate={minimalDate()}
   initialDate={new Date()}
   disabledDates={disableDate()}
   onDateChange={(res) => setSelectedDate(moment(res).format("D MMMM YYYY"))}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass date as a parameter to your function Try this,

```
const disableDate = (date) => {
  return date.getDay() === 0;
}
```